# Screen Validation With Data Annotations on Button Click in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-annotations, idataerrorinfo

I'm having a WPF Form contains a Single Property "**`PersonName`**". I wish to raise error on **`NULL OR EMPTY`**. I got a solution from **Data Annotations**, I refereed the tutorial http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/20c06b/screen-validation-with-data-annotations-in-wpf/

My XAML is

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PersonName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
 NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />

<Button Content="Save" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
 IsEnabled="{Binding }" Width="150" Height="40"/>
```

I can able to see the error only on **`onPropertyChange`** event. If I directly hit the button without touching the `TextBox` means, I can't able to see the Error. How could I trigger the same functionality on **`Button`** Click.

My Requirement is PersonName Should not be **`NULL`** or **`EMPTY`**, If the Property is **`NULL`** or **`EMPTY`**, then I need to disabled the Button, based on **`IDataErrorInfo`** not by **`Property.Length`**

Initial, we don't apply any validation. Once wrong data entry or without value hitting Button, then I need a validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IDataErrorInfo interface and inplement it as below like

```
public class ABC : IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _PersonName;
    public string PersonName
    {
        get { return _PersonName; }
        set
        {
            _PersonName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PersonName");
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if ("PersonName" == columnName)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PersonName))
                {
                    return "Your Error Message";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and also change the xaml as

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PersonName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
```

Comment: ViewModel class which contain the PersonName property . Implement  IDataErrorInfo interface method to that class. Can you share class name that contain PersonName  property

Comment: you can refer this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/858492/WPF-Validation-Using-IDataErrorInfo demo project

Comment: I'm asking where to bind the Validation Trigger in Button Click...? at the time of Button click I need to validate.

Comment: In Icommad there are two methods Execute and CanExecute. You can add  "return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(PersonName)" this code in  canexecute   method.

Comment: Yes I know that. I need to validate using `IDataErrorInfo`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a `ValidationRule` to your `TextBox` like in the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx)
then set a trigger on your `Button`

```
<Button Content="Save" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding SaveCommand} Width="150" Height="40">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=PersonName}" Value="False"/>
              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: How could I bind this with the Button?